# Loop sql-php conditional 5 times then exit

Tags: php, sql, database

I am not great with php/sql - still learning.

I am trying to get it so 5 url's (there are over 20 to chose from) are randomly selected from the user database and displayed on a page. In the event that the user has not filled out all 20+ url's in the members area of our site, I want it to skip the ones they have not filled out.

The problem is it is selecting and displaying 5 whether they are NULL or not and stopping after 5. Its not only counting the ones that are not null.

What do I need to fix, how would I go about this? I pasted the entire code from the page in question - hope its not to much to understand what I need.... like I say I am not that good at this stuff.

```
<?php
include "config.php";
if ($_GET['r']) {

    if($_COOKIE['referid']!=$_GET['r']) mysql_query("UPDATE members SET hits_unique=hits_unique+1,hits_visitor=hits_visitor+1 WHERE userid='".$_GET['r']."'");
    else mysql_query("UPDATE members SET hits_visitor=hits_visitor+1 WHERE userid='".$_GET['r']."'");

setcookie('referid', $_GET['r'], time()+365*24*60*60);
setcookie('referrer', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], time()+365*24*60*60);
}

include 'headsplash.php';
echo '<body style="font-family: "Lato", sans-serif; background-color: black; color: white; height:100%; overflow:hidden;">';
echo '<script src="modernizr-0.9.min.js"></script>';
echo '<canvas id="theapt" style="width:100%; height:100%; position:fixed; top:0;left:0; background-color:black; z-index:-1;"></canvas>';
echo '<center><h1 id="congrats" style="font-size:55px; margin: 0 6px 20px;">'.$_GET['r'].' Recommends</h1></center>';
echo '<div style="margin-bottom:5px; font-size:17px; text-align:center;">';

echo '\'s Downline Builder</h2>';
echo '<div class="wall_back shadow" style="opacity: .9; width:478px; margin: 15px auto 0; border: 1px solid white; border-radius:10px; padding:20px; background-color: #161616;">';


//Get the user links

$ub = array();

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM builder WHERE userid = '".$_GET['r']."'");

if(@mysql_num_rows($sql)) $ub = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

$lastcat = "";

    //Get the links for each site

    $slist = mysql_query("SELECT s.*,c.name as catname FROM builder_sites s JOIN builder_cat c ON s.category=c.id ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5");

while($each = mysql_fetch_array($slist)) {
$user = $_GET['r'];

$found = 0;

while($found == 0) {

    //Referrer exists?

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT m.referid FROM members m JOIN members r ON m.referid = r.userid WHERE m.userid = '".$_GET['user']."'");

    if(@mysql_num_rows($sql)) {

        $referrer = mysql_result($sql, 0);

        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT site".$each['id']." FROM builder WHERE userid = '".$_GET['r']."'");

        if(@mysql_num_rows($sql)) {


            // Found a row, check if it's empty

            $value = mysql_result($sql, 0);

            if($value) {

                //found a link, end the loop

                $links = $value;

                $found = 1;

            } else {

                //No link, next.

                $user = $referrer;

            }

        } else {

            //No row, next.

            $user = $referrer;

        }

    } else {

        //No more referrers, use default values

        $links = $each['url'];

        $found = 1;

    }



}



if($lastcat != $each['category']) ;

$lastcat = $each['category'];   



?>





        <table width="50%" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">

            <tr>







<form method="post"><a href="http://nullreferrer.com/go/?<? if($ub['site'.$each['id']]=="") echo $links; else echo $ub["site".$each['id']]; ?>" target="_blank"><? echo $each['desc']; ?></a><input type="hidden" name="sid" value="<? echo $each['id']; ?>">
<br><b><? echo $each['explain']; ?></b>




</form>

</tr>
        </table>









<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){ (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-41048281-1', 'thedownliner.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

  </script> 











 <? }
echo '<center><h3><br><a href="http://thedownliner.com/?r='.$_GET['r'].'" ><button id="button-green">Get your FREE downline builder here</button></a></h3></center>';


echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';

mysql_close($dblink);

?>
```

Comment: why not filter out the empty rows using a where clause?

Comment: @Jim thats exactly what I keep trying.... 

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT site".$each['id']." FROM builder WHERE userid = '".$_GET['r']."' WHERE site IS NOT NULL");

that seems to ignore the ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5 on

$slist = mysql_query("SELECT s.*,c.name as catname FROM builder_sites s JOIN builder_cat c ON s.category=c.id ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5");

Comment: you don't use two where statements.  ...from builder where userid = '" .$_GET['r'].'" AND is not null(site).